# Asp MVC how implement a page calendar

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

in asp mvc how can i implement a calendar like this one?
In a page there is some controls that permit to shift the month/year and when selected the month/year i can see some table data

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue) is a good example using ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Kendo. We have been using it for a while now, pretty awesome!

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index